# Interpretation of predictions of sparse_categorical_crossentropy keras model

Tags: keras, text, deep-learning, interpretation

I am trying to train a model to classify news. I'm using the bbc-text database:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eThnC.png)

I have transformed both, the output and input variables to be used in a keras model using Tokenizer().

Finally, I have set up the following model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(20000, 200, input_length=250),
tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')])


model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_text, y_train_text, batch_size=32, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_test_text, y_test_text))
```

While I get a good accuracy for this model, I do not know how to interpret the predictions. I would have expected to get, for each input, a list of 5 probabilities (summing up to 1), as my output has 5 possible categories.

Instead, I get this:
[Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAuY6.png)

Any help please?

Comment: your model classify between 6 classes not 5 (see the last Dense layer). They sum up to 1 for every sequence. Your output has batch dimension  because you are trying to predict for a set of sequences not one

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrey. Indeed that´s the main issue I am facing with this model (which I did not create, I am trying to use it for my problem).  I have tried to change the 6 for a 5 in the last Dense layer, which I think would be appropiate as my output variable has 5 categories. However, I get an error when trying to do so.

Comment: the only way is to find out the right six categories